# Web App can't create prompts "Request Timed Out"

Tags: powershell, iis, web-applications

When I try to create a new web application, it is taking forever to do so though I have 16GB RAM on my machine.

Content DB is created, but no IIS site.
Then it prompts "Request Timed Out". I tried to increase the timeout to 300, 400 and 900 in IIS, again no luck.
I tried creating a web application via Powershell, but still, it takes forever. I Can't find anything useful in logs as well.

I believe it's a permission related issue, can somebody guide me in the right direction? What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked the IIS log about how long it takes to return time out? Have you tried to expend shud down time limit for application pool? If you need to troubleshooting permission issue, please use process monitor to trace all I/O status. It will tell you where the permission should be grantedhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon